# Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, updatecommand, selectcommand

I have set PK for all Admin tables. They were working fine in the website. 
It's still working in the VM, when I debug the application using F5.

But the same code when deployed to IIS website, throwing this error all of the sudden. I didn't change any code specific to this issue.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Code - GridView1_RowUpdating:

CmdCommon.Connection = CnCommon

CmdCommon.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

CmdCommon.CommandText = "GetParameters"

Da = NewSqlDataAdapter(CmdCommon)

Da.Fill(Ds)

Dim myBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder= NewSqlCommandBuilder(Da)

myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
 
Da.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()

Ds.Tables(0).Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("ParamValue") = TxtParamValue.Text

Da.Update(Ds)
 Ds.AcceptChanges()

Comment: Code - Populate Grid: 

CmdCommon.Connection = CnCommon
CmdCommon.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
CmdCommon.CommandText = "GetParameters"

Da = New SqlDataAdapter(CmdCommon)
Da.Fill(Ds)

GridView1.DataSource = Ds
GridView1.DataBind()